# Magento 2 My site's header now show for the first load after flush the cache

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, header

After i flush all cache and delete my browser's history and try to reach my site as a new visitor my site's header not show no matter how much time i wait.
When i refresh the page its show up with no problem.
This error applies to the whole header section including search bar,cart,profile,logo, etc.

Im using custom theme with varnish and memcached.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clear, var > generation, folders and files everything in there. Then wait a few minutes until the cronjobs run, after that hard refresh (CTRL+R).